# Trouble determining onclick's target

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've tried and tried, and I can't seem to make this work in IE (tested version 6).
Can anybody help me? IE complains about an error but refuses to tell which error it is:

```
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].getAttribute("class") == "info-link") {
      a[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
        var info = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        if (info.style.display == "none" || info.style.display == "") {
          info.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          info.style.display = "none";
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

<div class="auxdata">
  <a href="#" class="info-link">Esta questão possuí dados anexos. Clique para ver.</a>
  <div style="display: none;" class="info-inner">
    <!-- variable stuff here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should seriously consider using a javascript framework to avoid these nitty gritty browser-specific details. jQuery is nice.

Comment: the thing is: i am supposed to use this inside the html file, to keep it self-contained :)

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: it works in every other browser except IE... the DOM's fine :)

Comment: @Pedro: `target` is affected by your DOM structure (specifically, the children inside `<a class="info-link">`), so cough it up.

Comment: Woops, just noticed `getAttribute("class")`. Try `.className` instead.

Comment: <div class="auxdata">
  <a href="#" class="info-link">Esta questão possuí dados anexos. Clique para ver.</a>
  <div style="display: none;" class="info-inner">
    <!-- variable stuff here -->
  </div>
</div>

Comment: I'm sorry for the horrible formatting... I don't know how to include code in a comment :\
Anyway, the code above is generated from an xml file, via xslt :)

Comment: did you try with the developer toolbar - still no clue wrt the error?

Comment: It works fine in firefox... i decided to include jquery as a dependency hence the problem is now "solved" :) thank you all

Answer (score 0):

IE before version 8 didn't do getAttribute('class') correctly, try reading the elements className property.

When you get past that, check how IE is reading the style property-
it may capitalize style values that are lower-case in the source, like 'NONE', 'BLOCK'.

Answer (score 0):

As *@Magnar* said (+1), I would include jQuery, it has a simple to use

```
jQuery(elem OR "selector").click(function(e){}).
```

At the very least you can look inside its code and see how it does the click() handle